# Having issues getting video to work correctly

Tags: boot, video

I've installed Ubuntu on several machines before and have never had this particular issue. I installed 20.04 on my old Dell Inspiron 3452 laptop. The install went fine, but I'm having issues getting the video to work correctly. Here's the situations I'm seeing:

1. Booting without `nomodeset` parameter: The screen goes black during boot and doesn't ever show anything. The Dell splash and the GRUB menu are in the correct resolution.
2. Booting with `nomodeset` parameter: It boots correctly, but it is stuck in 1366x768 resolution and doesn't respond when additional monitors are plugged in. This is (I believe) the expected behavior in this scenario. The Dell splash and the GRUB menu are in the correct resolution.
3. Booting without `nomodeset` parameter AND with a external display plugged in via HDMI: It seems to boot correctly and the displays are identified correctly. However, the Dell splash and the GRUB menu are in a lower resolution.
4. Booting with `nomodeset` parameter AND with a external display plugged in via HDMI: It boots correctly, but it is stuck in 1024x768 resolution and doesn't respond when additional monitors are plugged in. The Dell splash and the GRUB menu are in a lower resolution.

Here's the output of `lspci -k` for Scenario 2:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
    Kernel modules: mei_txe
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 35)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Dell Wireless 1801
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

If I run the same command in Scenario 3, then I get an additional line (the line with the asterisks):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
    **Kernel driver in use: i915**
    Kernel modules: i915
```

This seems to suggest that the i915 driver is not configured correctly.

Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this so it will boot correctly without a second display plugged in, but not by using `nomodeset` so it will recognize external displays if present? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an open bug report for kernel 5.8.0-36 and nvidia compilation issues.  What works for me:  Boot without nomodeset.  When the computer hangs, open tty2 and then return to tty1:  (ctrl-alt-f2 then ctrl-alt-f1) - my computer completes the boot sequence when I do this.

Comment: I tried this a few times, and unfortunately it didn't work